# How to change the right bottom text in horizontal Progres Dialog?

Tags: android, progressdialog

When i upload image, i show percentage to user. On the right buttom, i want to show "uploadedSize/fileSize". But i couldn't find how to set this text.

How can i change this text?

[image: ProgressDialogImg]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set by this method:

```
mProgressDialouge.setProgressNumberFormat (String format);
```

**Description:** Change the format of the small text showing current and maximum units of progress. The default is "%1d/%2d". Should not be called during the number is progressing.

**Parameters :**
format  A string passed to String.format(); use "%1d" for the current number and "%2d" for the maximum. If null, nothing will be shown.

further more info check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)